# pyface FileDialog with different default filename when wildcard changes

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, enthought, traitsui, pyface

I would like to provide a user with different default file names based on the wildcard that they select.

It seems that [pyface.FileDialog](https://github.com/enthought/pyface/commits/master/pyface/ui/wx/file_dialog.py) inherits from [HasTraits](https://github.com/enthought/pyface/blob/b149f5f88913480f822bec128f108782e116100c/pyface/ui/wx/widget.py#L23) so I should be above to observe it's [wildcard_index](https://github.com/enthought/pyface/blob/b149f5f88913480f822bec128f108782e116100c/pyface/ui/wx/file_dialog.py#L41) trait to notice the change and update the [default_filename](https://github.com/enthought/pyface/blob/b149f5f88913480f822bec128f108782e116100c/pyface/ui/wx/file_dialog.py#L41) trait.

Here are my versions,

```
import pyface, traits, traitsui
pyface.__version__, traits.__version__, traitsui.__version__
('6.1.2', '5.1.2', '6.1.3')
```

EDM python environment

```
import sys
sys.version
'2.7.15 |Enthought, Inc. (x86_64)| (default, Jun 21 2018, 22:10:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Using the WX backend

```
import wx
wx.version()
'3.0.2.0 msw (classic)'
```

Here is the simplest possible demo. of the problem,

```py
from pyface.api import FileDialog
from traits.api import on_trait_change

class MyFileDialog(FileDialog):
    """ Subclass that allows the suggested file name to change based on the wildcard type.
    """

    @on_trait_change('wildcard_index')
    def on_wildcard_changed(self, idx):
        # This is never called
        self.default_filename = [
            'filename_john',
            'filename_paul',
            'filename_george',
            'filename_ringo'][idx]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    types = ["*.a", "*.b", "*.c", "*.d"]
    dialog = MyFileDialog(
        action="save as",
        wildcard="|".join(["%s|%s" % (t, t) for t in types]),
    )
    dialog.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you post this question to the ets-users google group (For viewers not familiar with it, this is at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ets-users).